# How to sequence-identifier?

Tags: java, hibernate

In our old architektur we used id's like this:

```
/**
  * Model for each database-object
  */
public abstract class AbstractDbBase {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
}
```

But we got some issues, while changing values outside of Hibernate.
So we decide to use `bigserial` from `postgres`.

We changed our database and added for a each table a seqeunce and set it as primary key.
We have a lot of entities and all of them using the `AbstractDbBase`. And in `AbstractDbBase` is the defintion of the id.

But now we cant set Hibernate to use the sequence correctly.
We tried the following stragegies (for the `@GeneratedValue()`-annotation):

- `GenerationType.IDENTITY`: Throws excepetion when create records over hibnerate (no access to the sequence).
- `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`: Throws validation-exception (no sequence found).
- `GenerationType.AUTO`: Throws validation-exception (no sequence found).

My question is: How we can tell Hibernate to use the correct sequence? (Without write explicit the sequence-name for each entity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this: [hibernate could not get next sequence value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628099/hibernate-could-not-get-next-sequence-value)

So I have to use `GenerationType.IDENTITY`. Now I have to solve the "no permission for the sequence"-issue.
This have I done with this question: [ERROR: permission denied for sequence cities_id_seq using Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325017/error-permission-denied-for-sequence-cities-id-seq-using-postgres)

It works now.